# What is the right way to work 2 static 2d arrays in C?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameters, static

I have 2 static matrices.
a[][N] and b[][M].
Both N and M are pre defined and are not equal to each other. Now how am I supposed to write functions that can recieve them both and work properly?

```
void PrintStaticMatrix(int matrix[][??], int rows, int cols);
```

What am I going to need to put insted of ??. The naive way is to seperate the function into two functions; they will be exactly the same, but one is for N and the other one is for M. Howeve, it does not seem to make any sense. Is not there a better way? I would have much perferred to use only dynamic arrays, but we are forced to in an advanced C course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler supports variable length arrays you can declare the function like

```
void PrintStaticMatrix( int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols] );
```

or

```
void PrintStaticMatrix( int rows, int cols, int matrix[][cols] );
```

or

```
void PrintStaticMatrix( int rows, int cols, int ( *matrix )[cols] );
```

Another approach is to use dynamically allocated arrays as for example

```
int **matrix = malloc( rows * sizeof( int * ) );
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    matrix[i] = malloc( cols * sizeof( int ) );
}
```

And declare the function like

```
void PrintStaticMatrix( int **matrix, int rows, int cols );
```

One more approach is reinterpret a two-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array. In this case the function will look like

```
void PrintStaticMatrix( int *matrix, int rows, int cols );
```

And a function call can look like

```
PrintStaticMatrix( ( int * )matrix, rows, cols );
```

Within the function you will deal with a one-dimensional array. Using an appropriate expression as an index you will be able to simulate a two-dimensional array for example in for loops.

Otherwise you will need two separate functions like

```
void PrintStaticMatrix1( int matrix[][M], int rows );
```

and

```
void PrintStaticMatrix2( int matrix[][N], int rows );
```

Comment: The important thing is that the `cols` parameter has to be before the `matrix` parameter, right?

Comment: @Barmar Otherwise you can  can not  specify the array.

Comment: My visual studio 2019 compiler does not allow it. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Algo It seems you are compiling the program as a C++ program. VLA is not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: Does VS support VLA? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Algo Wait a minute. I will check MS VS 2019.

Comment: @Algo Yes. it seems MS VS 2019 does not support VLA.

Comment: Так что ты посоветуешь?

Comment: @Algo See my updated post.

Comment: @Algo in C++ you could use a template function.

Comment: @Algo See my appended answer.